# How to do mass sql operation in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have around 200 database all managed under cpanel phpmyadmin. I need to make similar edits to each of this operation. (2 SQL statements)

I would like to know how do i execute the queries so that it can alter the tables all in all the 200 database. (is there a feature to alter all dbs )

Have no issue executing the queries, however i feel it is inefficient as what i am doing now is to click into each db and execute the sql for that db -> have to do 200+ times.

Comment: 200 databases? That sounds a lot. Are you sure it's not 200 tables in a database?

Comment: yes! its 200 databases, not tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, you can do following:

```
// Connect to your mysql server
mysql_connect(...);

// Execute command which gets you list of all database from mysql server
$rs = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");

// Loop through all of them and execute your sql statements;
while ( $ds = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs) )
{

    mysql_select_db( $ds['Database'] );
    $sql = "some sql";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I think something like above should serve the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. I just updated my 200 databases with a click. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could develop either a stored procedure or a php script to build up dynamic queries and execute them on the fly.